# Regex to capture multiple tokens comma separated with quotes

Tags: java, c#, .net, regex

I do have a challenge to refine a regex expression that does try to parse input string as follows

Input String as follows

```
String input = "";
    CProfi ( "USA2.00", "zeBra")
    BFile(3F2, TTT, 10)
    SVendor(D&D)
    // JohnDow(2255, 99, "Joe")
    SProtocol(11.32_DD, 99)
    SProtocol(22.22_C&c)
    Description("Boo")
    Test(d)
    TTTTT(000000)
    Descr3("Hello Worlkd!", "I am back", 3)
```

I did try to use many variations of the following Regex, without success

```
Regex = "^\s*(?<Key>[^\(]+)\s*\(\s*(?<Param>(".*?"|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*))"
```

Any help to fix this pattern so all of the parameters are captured, not only the first or only the last one

Comment: What's your expected output? Which lang did you prefer?

Comment: @Raj  thX for the help. I am using java. I am trying to parse all values that are parameters with named group.

Comment: could you provide the output you expected?

Comment: @Raj for example I would like to breaknown // Descr3("Hello Worlkd!", "I am back", 3) // into key=Descr3 / Param=[Hello Wolkd!] / Param=[I am back] / Param=[3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use need to use `\G` anchor to do a continuous string match.

```
(?:(?<Key>\S+) *\( *|(?<!^)\G) *"?(?<param>[^",\n]*)"?,?(?=[^()\n]*\))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kV1vS3/1)

**Update:**

```
(?:^(?:(?!\/\/).)*\b(?<Key>\S+) *\( *|(?<!^)\G) *"?(?<param>[^",\n]*)"?,?(?=[^()\n]*\))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kV1vS3/2)

Comment: Hello Raj
Great combination for those switches, I did try to use it, but if I do add a line comment (//) it is still matching the line, I did try to add ^ at the beginning, but did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: add an example which reflects the above comment in your question.

Comment: @Raj, take a look at the edited input string. Also how do you get all the hits of the same group name in this pattern. As you could see the param group has sometime more than one hit, .... Thx in advance

Comment: @Raj, Thx a lot, that did address the issue of capturing all tokens needed, and does exclude the comments. Did have any suggestions on the correct code to retrieve all the matches that do have the same group name (<code>param<c/ode> in this case) using Java 7 (that does support named group). cheers.